# Windows 10 USB Wifi adapter disabled at startup

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, usb

After multiple [unsolvable networking issues](https://superuser.com/questions/1317418/windows-10-cant-connect-to-from-network-shares) with Windows 10, I decided to reinstall (after trying the full "refresh" option, which unfortunately didn't do a whole lot).

After reinstalling, I have a new problem which wasn't happening previously: My HUAWEI LTE USB WIFI adapter is disabled after shutting down, every time. It can be resolved by quickly unplugging from USB and reconnecting, after 3 seconds it is again set to enabled and works fine.

I also have a LAN connection to the internet via a different, albeit much slower provider, as well as a Cisco AnyConnect VPN network adapter which is mostly disabled.

I also am using batch files to set the metric, since the LTE is my primary internet and the LAN is only a backup and generally only used to connect to other devices in the network - and because Windows assumes the LAN connection is the fastest, thereby setting the metric to the highest priority...

```
rem remove existing routes
route delete 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.13.1
route delete 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 172.22.250.1
route delete 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1

rem LTE has highest prio
route add -p 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.13.1 metric 10

rem LAN
route add -p 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 metric 50

rem VPN
route add -p 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 172.22.250.1 metric 51
```

The LTE USB modem Power Management option to turn off the device to save power is disabled.

Checking Event Viewer, I see no errors or warnings relating to anything networking.

How can I force Windows 10 to enable my LTE modem during startup?

Edit:

According to Device manager, all drivers are accounted for:
[image]

The device driver is 1.0.17.0 (7/10/2014) from HUAWEI. There are no available updates, nor any updates or drivers to be found via Googling or on HUAWEI's website.

Comment: You are probably missing a driver. What is the exact model of the Wi-Fi adapter?

Comment: E5786s-32a otherwise known as "E5786 4G LTE". I can't seem to find any drivers anywhere. It's amazing, when I try to search Huawei Support for anything related to this device, they don't even recognize the model number!

Comment: These might be helpful: [link1](http://www.mfbernardes.com/how-to-get-huawei-e3272-working-on-macos-sierra/) and [link2](https://www.modemunlock.com/huawei-mac-os-x-driver-installation.html).

Comment: Unfortunately both of those links are for OSX.

Comment: Sorry, mix up with another post.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/downloads/ds111977) will help.

Comment: According to the readme, this driver is for "Huawei Mobile Connect-Gps" and support for Windows 10 was removed in "12.1805.10.6", yet there are instructions for how to install/uninstall from Windows 10! Regardless, I will give it a try in a couple days when I have a chance to do more dangerous tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately that was the wrong driver. On the upshot, I just finished a complete Win10 reinstall (including drive format) and the problem seems to have gone away. On the other hand, I am having other strange/annoying behavior. Win10 is such a clusterf***.